# How to properly get JSON after AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I've spent a lot of time on this task and did hours of research but I still don't have a solution to this.

I get an **401 error**

But if I add this at the end of the url:  **?jsonpcallback=?**

I get this in the console: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**

Can someone guide me on this please and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance!

Here's my code:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "XXX/jsonpcallback=?",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain:true,
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a crossDomain request-- you sure you need jsonp?

Comment: @anied I'm not really sure if I need jsonp, I just want to be able to console out the JSON that comes back from the server, that is all. Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Comment: What happens if you just use `dataType: 'json'`, remove the `crossDomain` property and leave the `jsonpcallback` query parameter off the url?

Comment: @anied I just did what you suggested and got this error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin as well as 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Oh, wait, sorry, I think I misread this.  Where are you making the calls from?  Like, is `mensajesdevoz.co` your site?  Or some other site?  Are you working locally at the moment?

Comment: @anied Its not locally, you can try it and you'll see that JSON that I'm trying to get back

Comment: The URL that you provided is returning JSON even with the `?jsonpcallback=?` argument. You can't do a cross-domain call for JSON unless the response has the correct header, which apparently it doesn't. But you can't just say `type:'jsonp'` and treat the JSON as if it were JSON-P - it's trying to use it as JSON-P but it isn't, hence the error message.

Comment: @nnnnnn any ideas how to accomplish this then? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you don't control the end point, I think the usual way is to make a normal Ajax request to your own web server, have your server-side code make a request to the other server, and then return the results back to the browser that way.

Comment: @nnnnnn that's what I've been trying to do, but still no luck :(

Comment: @nnnnnn whenever I do the normal Ajax I see that the status is 200 and the value for readyState is always 4, but I cannot output the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$.getJSON('XXX/jsonpcallback=?xxx', function(data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```